# Ubuntu 18.04 jumps to single display mode on opening terminal

Tags: command-line, 18.04, nvidia, display, settings

Every time I'm open regular terminal or open bash inside VCode or inside any other programs that are using/opening regular terminal - I'm loosing secondary display connection and staying with single display mode.

after running

```
sudo lshw -C display && sudo lspci | grep -i vga
```

```
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller product: GP107GLM [Quadro P2000 Mobile] 
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation physical id: 0 
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0 
version: a1 width: 64 bits clock: 33MHz 
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom 
configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0 
resources: irq:149 memory:e8000000-e8ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:e9080000-e90fffff 01:00.0 VGA compatible 
controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GLM [Quadro P2000 Mobile] (rev a1)
```